# Can't pass ViewBag info to the DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I have the following problem:

I create Db context and then transfer it to IQueryable. After that I extract distinct values. It queries the results perfectly (I checked in debugger). I create the viewbag:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var forDistinct = db.Cases.AsQueryable();
    var Issue_Type = forDistinct.DistinctBy(x => x.Issue_Type).Select(col => col.Issue_Type).ToList();
    ViewBag.DropDown = new SelectList(Issue_Type);
    return View();
}
```

I set the DropDownListFor as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Issue_Type, ViewBag.DropDown as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

When I try to save new item, the following error occurs:

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'Issue_Type' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Post Method like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
 var forDistinct = db.Cases.AsQueryable();
 var Issue_Type = forDistinct.DistinctBy(x => x.Issue_Type).Select(col =>
 col.Issue_Type)/*.Select(grp => grp.First()*/.ToList();
 ViewBag.DropDown = new SelectList(Issue_Type);
 return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Declare ViewBags both in get and post methods!

Answer (score 0):

Error is obvious DropDown should be like :

```
ViewBag.DropDown = forDistinct.DistinctBy(x => x.Issue_Type).Select(col=> new SelectListItems { Text= col.Issue_Type,Value=col.Issue_Type.ToString() }).ToList();
```

because your dropdown expecting IEnumerable